# How do I decimal-align numbers in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I want to decimal-align numbers without adding trailing zeros in the fractional part.

```
Instead of:  I want:
+------+     +------+
|  56.0|     |  56  |
|  27.0|     |  27  |
|  83.0|     |  83  |
|   2.4|     |   2.4|
|   1.2|     |   1.2|
| 120.0|     | 120  |
+------+     +------+
```

The format of the first column is easily accomplished (for example, using the format "0.0" or just setting custom decimal points under the 123 button).

In Excel, I believe the format of the second column is accomplished using the format "0.?", but as of this writing it does not work in Google Sheets.

### Workaround

It is possible to force trailing characters with Substitute:

```
= Substitute( Text( formula ; "0.0" ) ; ".0" ; "  ")
= Substitute( Text( formula ; "0.0" ) ; ".0" ; "__" )
```

Note: the two substituted whitespace characters are not *U+0020 SPACE* but *U+2002 EN SPACE*. (*U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE* also works.)

Some undesirable side effects of this workaround are that it

- modifies not just the display format but also the value of the cell
- requires the use of a monospaced font in the cell
- trailing whitespace causes font substitution due to the Unicode and does not print correctly
- trailing underlines are not as desirable as trailing whitespace
- confuses maintainers because it is not evident that an EN SPACE is being used
- (presumably) fails in locales which use the period as the period separator (thousands separator) instead of the decimal marker

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the following custom number format, you are able to decimal-align numbers in Google Sheets, even by using fonts that use kerning.

### Custom format

```
???.?????
```

### Screenshot

*custom number format*
[image]

*result*
[image]

### Example

I've added this solution in an example file: **[Decimal-Aligned Numbers](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdF8zYVE3SXRnT3ItQ0QtYXZNYVl6N2c&usp=sharing)**

Comment: Support for the "?" format character was absent when I originally asked the question. I wonder if it was added as part of Google's recent support of [accounting number formats](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/02/support-for-rotated-text-accounting.html). This is a useful workaround, very close to what I want. The only limitation is that a decimal point appears even when there is no fractional part. In Excel, that limitation can be worked around with conditional formatting. But not, it seems, in Sheets. I am accepting this answer.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote some code to make your live a bit easier, in displaying decimal-aligned numbers.

### The first code

can only be used in a range, because it dynamically changes the appearance of the numbers according to the highest decimal place in the range. It also allows you to chose the trailing character, like CHAR(160):

```
function RANGETRAIL(range,chr){
  chr = chr || '0'; 
  var aValues = new Array(), aDecimals = new Array();

  var max=0;
  for(i in range) {
    if(range[i] != "") {
      var string = range[i].toString();
      aValues.push([string]);
      var aSplit = string.split("."); 

      if(aSplit.length > 1) {
        aDecimals.push([aSplit[1].length]);
        if(aSplit[1].length > max) {
          max = parseInt(aSplit[1].length);        
        } 
      } else {
        aDecimals.push(["-1"]);
      }
    }
  } 

  for(k in aDecimals) {
    if(parseInt(aDecimals[k]) != parseInt(max)) {
      for(var l=parseInt(aDecimals[k]); l<parseInt(max); l++) {        
        aValues[k][0] += chr;
      }
    }
  }     
  return aValues;
}
```

---

### The second code

is meant to be used for cells. Here you need to set the trailing length:

```
function CELLTRAIL(cell,len,chr){
  // Brad Christie, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5024108/1536038
  chr = chr || '0'; 
  cell = cell.toString();

  if (!len) return cell;

  var p = cell.indexOf('.');
  p = (p!==-1?(cell.length-p-1):-1);

  for (var m = p; m < len; m++) {
    cell += chr;
  }
  return cell;
}
```

---

### The third code

will strap a string from all non-numerics, except a "." and ",":

```
function RTRIM(cell) {   
  return Number(cell.replace(/[^0-9$.,]/g, ''));
}
```

### Example File

**[Decimal-Aligned Numbers](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdF8zYVE3SXRnT3ItQ0QtYXZNYVl6N2c&usp=sharing)**
[image]

---

### Thoughts

This answer doesn't take away the concerns you mentioned in your question, but it will give some automation (dynamically) in displaying them !! Good luck.

Comment: I'd like to point out that this can lead to strange alignment problems if you aren't using a fixed width font.

Comment: @mir thanks for your comment Mir. Did you like the answer I gave? In the _thoughts heading_ I explained that it wouldn't take away the concerns the OP gave.

Comment: The answer was actually really helpful once I realized that I needed to use a fixed width font. I'll be honest - I didn't read the question carefully... I just glanced at it to confirm that it was similar to my issue, then jumped straight to your answer. So I didn't notice that OP included concerns about the fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the format conditionally by using an Apps Script to iterate over the range of cells and apply different [Custom Number Formats](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470) based on the value of the cell (integer vs non-integer). Using Custom Number Formats, you can display white spaces of varying width using the underscore character, for example, `_.` inserts white space the width of a period and `_0` inserts whitespace the width of a zero character. Incidentally, most fonts use the same width for all numeral characters so a 0 character is the same width as a 1 and 2 and 3 etc.

This is an example of how the numbers are displayed before and after applying the formatd by running the script. One drawback is that a change in the value of the cell from integer to non-integer or vice-versa will require the formatting to be re-applied to show or hide the decimal as needed.

```
  Raw Numbers  Decimal Aligned
+------------+----------------+
|    1234.777|         1,234.8|
|        5454|         5,454  |
|           7|             7  |
|         0.5|             0.5|
+------------+----------------+
```

Script

```
function decimalAlign() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sheet.getRange("B2:B5");
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
      var currentCell = range.getCell(i,j);
      var currentValue = currentCell.getValue();
      if (Math.round(currentValue) == currentValue) {
        currentCell.setNumberFormat("#,##0_._0");
      } else {
        currentCell.setNumberFormat("#,##0.0");
      }
    }
  }
}
```