# Allow trailing whitespaces in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I was working on a Google Spreadsheet and I found that it does not allow more than one white space anywhere.

Is there any option to stop auto trimming on text? I searched it but didn’t found any solution.

```
╔═══════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ what google gives ║ what I want ║
╠═══════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ text              ║    text     ║
╚═══════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: Can you share a doc with us and show us the expected outcome?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I just want that when I put spaces in beginning or end of text .. it should not get trimmed off

Comment: Have a look at this Q&A: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40297/29140

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra please see my edited question

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra not working

Comment: Haha, sorry for that.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra lolz... no problem. I thought it is some trick I am unaware of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a formula workaround which should work regardless of the OS, eg:

`=CHAR(160)&"text"`

`=CHAR(160)&CHAR(160)&"text"`

`=REPT(CHAR(160);3)&"text"`

Answer (score 1):

It kept removing extra spaces, even when I placed a character in the front (e.g. `=CHAR(160)&"text"`) and pasted those results over. Here's what worked for handling *leading* spaces (this solution won't accommodate text with trailing spaces):

Determine the number of leading/training spaces, in B1 enter:
`=LEN(A1)-LEN(TRIM(A1))`

Paste the original text over to Google sheets, along with the results from the formula used above that counts leading/trailing spaces.

Then in a new cell, enter:
`=REPT(" ",B1)&A1`

This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a leading ' in a text editor and then paste to google sheets.

```
'      <PRODUCTCODE>1002</PRODUCTCODE>
'      <PRODUCTDESC>EXAMPLE</PRODUCTDESC>
'      <AMOUNT>34000</AMOUNT>
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use the keystrokes "Alt+0160" or "Alt+255" to get it to indent.

You have to be in cell edit mode. Type the keystrokes above for a space. This solves your question "stop auto trimming on text" but your subject says "allow trailing white spaces". With the limited info I would say it works for that too.

This is useful for indenting and such in some formats.

Comment: thanks for your answer .. but I am using fedora os. When I press any number holding alt .. it changes the window ..

Comment: That being a critical part of your problem, would have been nice to see that in the question.