# How to left align currency symbol but right align number?

Tags: google-sheets

How to left align dollar sign and right align the number, like Excel currency format?

For example:

```
$    3,546
$   44,345
```

Also, is there a way to create a custom format?

Comment: Perhaps this can shed a light: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/42644/29140

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Highlight the cells you wish to be this way then click "Format" -> "Number" -> "Accounting".

Resourses

- [Support for rotated text, accounting number formats, and more in Google Sheets](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2017/02/support-for-rotated-text-accounting.html) from Wednesday, February 22, 2017

Answer (score 9):

*Asterisk (i.e. `*`) repeats the following character to fill in the remaining space in the cell.*

If you are willing to use a **custom number format** (perhaps because you want a different currency or don't like the way the accounting format displays negative numbers), the character that specifies this layout is the `*`, followed by a space.

Under `Format / Number / More Formats / Custom Number Format /`
 instead of e.g. 
`[$R] #,##0.00` put `[$R]* #,##0.00` (note the asterisk which is the only change) and you will get the desired effect.

In the `Custom Number Format` dialog there is a link to [help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?p=drive_custom_numbers)
 [(https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?p=drive_custom_numbers)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?p=drive_custom_numbers)

If you just want to make an small adjustment to a provided format that you mostly like, set the format of a cell to that format and ***then*** go to `Format / Number / More Formats / Custom Number Format /` and you will find the field pre-populated with the "format string" for the existing format. Some of them are quite complicated and you would not want to start from scratch e.g for accounting, it is `_("$"* #,##0.00_);_("$"* \(#,##0.00\);_("$"* "-"??_);_(@_)` !