# How to left align dollar symbol but right align number?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, text-formatting, customization

I selected format -> number -> more formats -> custom number format:

`$#,##0_);[Red]($#,##0)`

How can prepend spaces between the `$` symbol and the digits?  Pad with spaces.  So that the dollar sign is always on the left and the numbers on the right with the cell filled.

The [distinction](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/52479/24327) being that I want dollars and not British pounds, and only want to display whole numbers, not pennies.

Can't get the sequence down of which to apply first as those options seem to wipe each other out.

Update:  by clicking `Decrease Decimal Places` I have the British Pound, but with no decimal places and the currency symbol left aligned.

How do I change that to the dollar symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a combination of, yes, selecting "accounting" as freginold says.  I'd already done this.  By also moving the decimal and, then, finally, changing the locale from UK to USA I was able to get dollar signs left aligned, amount right aligned, with no decimal places.

Jeesh.  I only hope that helps someone out there.

Answer (score 7):

You can align your dollar amounts like that by selecting the **Accounting** format.

[image]

- Select **Format** on the menu
- Select **Number**
- Select **Accounting**

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

`_($* #,##0_);[Red]($* #,##0)`

Then be sure you left align your cell.

Answer (score 0):

Add a separate, very narrow column with the $\$$ in it, and format the number as you wish without a currency symbol.