# How do I add a dollar sign to the left in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I've seen the previous answer
[Highlight the cells you wish to be this way then click "Format" -> "Number" -> "Accounting".](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/109878/) Well, why to go to that trouble when the $ sign is visible at the top?

My question is how can I add it without saying CAD in front?

I do not want to choose a specific country just the $ sign, like I can do on the OpenOffice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I answer my own question.

Not sure if I created or was there and did not see it before.

"Format" -> "Number" -> "Accounting" then lower down the list has the $ itself.
Also, can be done by clicking on the little arrow next to 123. I'm all about saving time. :)