# How can I set a monospace font in a Google Sheets column?

Tags: google-sheets

How can I apply a `monospace` font to a Google Spreadsheet cell or column?  This capability is easy in Excel, Gnumeric, Libreoffice or other desktop spreadsheeets.  As of this writing, there's no font setting menu for cells in Google Sheets, and nothing on any context menu.

Why? I've got a series of part numbers to line up.  These line up poorly in a regular font:

- S34ML04G100BHI000
- W34ML08G200IHI000

And nicely in a fixed width font:

```
S34ML04G100BHI000
W34ML08G200IHI000
```

For a similar question about vertical aligment of numbers see [How do I decimal-align numbers in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/how-do-i-decimal-align-numbers-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 9):

There's a font selector right there in the default toolbar. Simply select your cell(s) (or a whole row or column) and then choose your font. "Courier New" and "Consolas" are both monospace fonts (I prefer the latter).

[image: Font selector]

Comment: The hell it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

There are several more options. They are detailed here: [Google's Monospaced Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace). Hopefully, Google will keep this link updated.

[image]

Comment: Instead of searching by the string "mono", click on **"Show: All fonts"** and select "Show: **Monospace**"